# What Causes Maintenance Shell Segmentation Fault?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, filesystems, data-recovery, segmentation-fault

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr in a Microsoft Hyper-V virtual machine on Windows Server 2012 R2.  I've stopped the VM, replaced an EXT4-formatted virtual disk volume (/dev/sdb) with a new (unformatted) disk volume and restarted the VM.  I see the following messages:

Filesystem check or mount failed.
A maintenance shell will now be started.
CONTROL-D will terminate this shell and continue booting after re-trying
filesystems.  Any further errors will be ignored
Give root password for maintenance
(or type Control-D to continue):

Upon typing the root password, I see:

Segmentation Fault

I would like to determine which process has caused the segmentation fault and why.  I am reproducing a issue that was brought to my attention and would like to provide an explanation for the segmentation fault.  Is it a bug in Ubuntu 14.04?  If so, is there a work-around?  If there is a work-around, I would like to see it documented here.

Comment: If you remove or change drives and udev doesn't have a persistent rule, then the drive location (/dev/sd?) may have changed.

Comment: The device path (/dev/sdb) remains the same.  The device is now associated with a new Hyper-V virtual hard disk.

Comment: The best work-around I have found so far is to attach a live distro to the DVD drive device and reboot the VM into the live distro, create a partition table, create and format a partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP and I worked through this; see comments & chat for details. First, to find the problem process and location, this line in `/etc/init/mountall-shell.conf`

```
/sbin/sulogin
```

was changed to

```
/usr/bin/ltrace -S -f -o /root/sulogin-ltrace.log /bin/sulogin
```

Excerpt from log:

```
837 crypt("password", "x") = nil
837 strcmp(nil, "x" <no return ...>
837 --- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)
```

The log indicates that the segfault occurs in the following code in `sulogin`, where `crypt` is returning NULL.

```
if ((p = getpasswd(pwd->pw_passwd)) == NULL) break;
if (pwd->pw_passwd[0] == 0 ||
    strcmp(crypt(p, pwd->pw_passwd), pwd->pw_passwd) == 0)
        sushell(pwd);
```

Next question is, what's causing crypt to return NULL?

OP confirmed that the encrypted password really was `x`; the shadow entry for root was `root:x:16273:0:99999:7:::`. In a stock Ubuntu 14.04, root's encrypted password is `!`; OP had changed it to `x` awhile ago and this is the first time since then that he's had to use single-user mode.

`sulogin` has its own interpretation of special encrypted passwords. If it sees `*` or `!`, it lets the user in with no password. Anything else, it does some validity checking, but `x` sails right through, yet `crypt` doesn't like it (salt not long enough?) and returns NULL.

OP is going to file a bug report for `sysvinit-utils`; `sulogin` ought to handle a NULL return from `crypt` more gracefully.

Comment: The last system call before the SIGSEGV is `write(1, "\n", 1) = 1`.

Comment: Can you tell which executable? Sulogin or a shell?

Comment: It would also be useful to see which files were accessed just before it died. Maybe a PAM module can't open a file.

Comment: It's /sbin/sulogin. I wish I could paste the entire log here, but I'm limited to a few hundred characters and cannot insert  newlines. The last two system calls were ioctl(0, ...) and write(1, ...).

Comment: I added an ltrace command to my answer. Can you try that? It will log the library calls.

Comment: At boot time, I see: `The disk drive for /var/opt/companyname/productname/data is not ready yet or not present.  keys:Continue to wait, or Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery`  I then press M for manual recovery.

Comment: I've run ltrace and the last two library calls are: `837 crypt("password", "x")                       = nil
837 strcmp(nil, "x" <no return ...>
837 --- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) ---`.  This looks like a bug in sulogin to me.

Comment: I looked at the source. `strcmp(crypt(...),"encryptedpassword")`. Not as robust as it could be, but the problem is that crypt() is returning NULL, which is very uncommon.

Comment: The man page for crypt() suggests that it returns NULL if an error is encountered.  It seems there should be a test for a NULL return from crypt().  Should I file a problem report?

Comment: Was the 2nd argument to crypt and strcmp really "x", or something else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15938/discussion-between-michael-g-morey-and-mark-plotnick).